# Getting RateLimitError while implementing openai GPT with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, openai-api, gpt-3

I have started to implement openai gpt model in python. I have to send a single request in which I am getting RateLimitError.

My code looks like this

```
import openai

key = '<SECRET-KEY>'
openai.api_key = key
model_engine = 'text-ada-001'
prompt = 'Hi, How are you today?'
completion = openai.Completion.create(engine=model_engine, prompt=prompt, max_token=2048, n=1, stop=None, temprature=0.5)
print(completion.choices)
```

This is what error I am getting

```
openai.error.RateLimitError: You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details.
```

So, How do I do development without getting this error? I have checked the doc they provide a free version with limitations but this is the initial stage I have sent only 5-6 requests in an hour.

Thanks advance for your help.

Comment: Did you do this inside a `for` loop at any point? What do the docs say are the limitations? The "rate limit" error could be referring to the frequency at which you were hitting the API.

Comment: No, I haven't used for loop. This is the only code I have written so far just to test so that I can proceed but getting error in this code only.

Comment: If you need to make more requests than that, then I guess you need to buy a plan.

Comment: @TimRoberts I have tried only 5-6 request and it is very less than the free trial

Comment: As I said it could also be the frequency at which you made the requests, not necessarily the number of requests you've made so far.

Answer (score 3):

Later versions (>= `1.0.0`) of the openai Python API include functionality to automatically retry requests. See [GitHub discussion](https://github.com/openai/openai-python/discussions/742).

Answer (score 2):

This probably stems from the server being overloaded. There is an [article](https://help.openai.com/en/articles/6897202-ratelimiterror) on OpenAI's help subdomain.

> If you encounter a RateLimitError, please try the following steps:
>
> - Wait until your rate limit resets (one minute) and retry your request. The error message should give you a sense of your usage rate
>   and permitted usage.
> - Send fewer tokens or requests or slow down. You may need to reduce the frequency or volume of your requests, batch your tokens, or
>   implement exponential backoff. You can read our rate limit guidance
>   here.
> - You can also check your usage statistics from your account dashboard.

More helpful info:

- https://help.openai.com/en/articles/6891753-rate-limit-advice
- https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/rate-limits/overview

The second link has limits that your script should take into account when making requests or retrying requests. All this info was found by doing a web search on "openai.error.RateLimitError".

Answer (score 1):

You can use e.g. https://github.com/phelps-sg/openai-pygenerator to automatically retry requests when a `RateLimitError` occurs.

Edit: the new 1.0.0 Python API includes functionality for automatically retrying requests.